# sitefinity collection data from API

Tags: sitefinity

Within Sitefinity can I collection data from a API and then join that data together with data that is Sitefinity database. I been thinking about this because there are control and tools in Sitefinity that it would be nice to leverage and can use the  review mode.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do - can you give some examples?

Comment: If I have one application that stores company news. Now I can it’s Expose api in that application that  Sitefinity can access. But what if I wanted to add an image to that news record can of be stored in Sitefinity? I don’t want the image stored in the application because Sitefinity has nice image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sitefinity API to create the Content Items in your Sitefinity site, e.g. News. Then, you can use the Sitefinity UI to add images or other media to the already created news item.

This should get you started: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-create-a-news-item-with-the-native-api

Comment: Thanks @veselin-vasilev is  `WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(masterNewsId, typeof(NewsItem), null, "Publish", false, bag);` is that going to set the item into the live site? Can I set it to review status?

Comment: Yes, that would publish the item, making it visible on the front-end. If you have a workflow enabled, then you can do something like this: WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(temp.Id, typeof(NewsItem), null, "SendForApproval", false, bag); // temp is the checked out master item, i.e. var temp = manager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(master) as NewsItem;